Scroll Getting Stuck When Changing Between The child components
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styles from './Styles.module.scss';
import Loader from '../../components/Loader/Loader';
import ScrolledBar from '../../components/ProgressBar/ProgressBar';
import MainSection from '../../components/MainSection/MainSection';
import MouseIcon from '../../components/MouseIcon/MouseIcon';

import { ReactIcon } from '../../components/svgs';
import { threshold } from 'three/webgpu';

const Home = () => {
  
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(true);
  const [snapScroll, setSnapScroll] = useState(false);
  const [blur, setBlur] = useState(false);

  const skills = [
    { skillName: 'React JS', skillImage: ReactIcon, skillLevel: 80, description: "" },
    { skillName: 'React Native', skillImage: ReactIcon, skillLevel: 70, description: "" },
    { skillName: 'Node JS', skillImage: ReactIcon, skillLevel: 60, description: "" },
    { skillName: 'Express JS', skillImage: ReactIcon, skillLevel: 60, description: "" },
    { skillName: 'Javascript', skillImage: ReactIcon, skillLevel: 89, description: "" },
    { skillName: 'Java', skillImage: ReactIcon, skillLevel: 56, description: "" },
    { skillName: 'Spring Boot', skillImage: ReactIcon, skillLevel: 70, description: "" },
    { skillName: 'Microserivces', skillImage: ReactIcon, skillLevel: 66, description: "" },
  ]

  useEffect(() => { 
    if(load) return;

    const snapSection = document.getElementById("SnapSection")!;

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.map((entry) => {
        setSnapScroll(entry.intersectionRatio == 1);
        setBlur(entry.intersectionRatio > 0.1);
      });
    }, {threshold: [.1, 1]});

    observer.observe(snapSection);

    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, [load]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(load) {
      setTimeout(() => setLoad(false), 2000);
      return;
    }
    
    const maximumScrollLength = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].clientHeight;
    console.log(maximumScrollLength);

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.map((entry) => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting) {
          entry.target.classList.add(styles.animateProgBar);
        } else {
          entry.target.classList.remove(styles.animateProgBar);
        }
      })
    })

    const progressBars = document.querySelectorAll(".progressBar");
    progressBars.forEach((a) => observer.observe(a));

  }, [load]);

  return load ? (<Loader />) : (
    <main className={`${styles.main}`}>
      <article>
        <MouseIcon />
        <ScrolledBar />
        <div className={`${styles.backEffect}`} ></div>
      </article>
      <article className='overscroll-auto'>
        <MainSection />
        <section id="SkillSection" className={`min-h-[100vh] flex flex-col gap-5 overscroll-auto justify-center items-center py-11 sticky top-0 transition-all ${blur && 'filter blur-sm' }`}>
          <div className='grid gap-3 w-[60%]'>
            { skills.sort((a, b) => b.skillLevel - a.skillLevel).map((a, i) => (
              <div className='flex flex-col gap-2' key={i}>
                <h1 className='font-iceberg text-3xl' >{a.skillName}</h1>
                <div className={`h-[10px] bg-yellow-300 rounded-lg relative`}>
                  <div className={`bg-red-500 h-[100%] overflow-visible rounded-lg flex justify-end items-center progressBar ${styles.progressBar}`} style={{ width: a.skillLevel+"%" }}>
                    <div className='w-6 aspect-square border p-1 rounded-lg' style={{ background: "var(--background-color)", borderColor: "var(--text-color)" }}>
                      {a.skillImage()}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </section> 
        <article id='SnapSection' className={`relative z-20 h-[100vh] overflow-hidden overscroll-auto  ${snapScroll && 'overflow-scroll snap-y snap-mandatory'}`}>
          <section className='p-10 w-[100%] h-[100vh] bg-red-400 snap-start'>Dev Garg</section>
          <section className='p-10 w-[100%] h-[100vh] bg-yellow-400 snap-start'>Dev Garg</section>
        </article>
            </article>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Home;

So I was Writing The Above Code in Which I have an Article which contains 3 different components MainSection, **SkillSection **and SnapSection. I wanted the main and SkillSection to scroll Normally then i wanted the Snap Section to appear and start Snaping the inner childs. I have somehow implemented the above said action but for some reason my scroll get stuck when shifting between the components i.e. SkillSection and SnapSection. I cant understand the reason. When snapSection is completly on the screen the scroll gets stuck and doesnt work until the mouse is moved.
For above feilds to not get Stuck i used various things like overscroll-behavious: auto. IntersectionObserver, etc but i can't seem to make it work. The scroll works properly initially but after some time it start causing problem (Stuck) again. I am activating snap-scroll only when the snapSection is completely loaded. But till i move my mouse slightly it doesnt switch the scroll between child components.
Also, Please help if there is any other better method to implement this functionality.

Try to use useTransition hook
